# how to retrieve matched value in a excel sheet with a user input using Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy

[example sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9QiO.png) How to retrieve matched value in a excel sheet with a user input using Python.

Consider below data is in a text.csv fiile.
If user inputs as 9 the my code needs to match the corresponding value if it which is 10.1.12.15

8   10.1.12.17
9   10.1.12.15
10  10.1.12.11
11  10.1.12.19
14  10.1.12.25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create DataFrame by [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and set first column to `index`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('text.csv', names=['col1','col2'], sep=',', index_col=[0])

print (df)
            col2
col1            
8     10.1.12.17
9     10.1.12.15
10    10.1.12.11
11    10.1.12.19
14    10.1.12.25
```

And then select by value `9` in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
val = 9
out = df.loc[val, 'col2']
print (out)
10.1.12.15
```

Comment: I believe col1 and col2 should be replaced by the name of the column in the code, right?

Comment: @pravinraj66 - Sure, if there is header in csv omit `names` parameteer

Comment: I get "raise KeyError(key) from err KeyError: '123' after providing the user input.

Comment: @pravinraj66 - What is `print (df.to_dict())` ater created DataFrame?

Comment: {'col2': {'7,10.1.12.15': nan, '8,10.1.12.15': nan, '9,10.1.12.15': nan, '10,10.1.12.15': nan, '11,10.1.12.15': nan, '14,10.1.12.15': nan, '17,10.1.12.15': nan}

Comment: I believe we need to teak somewhere to get the dict in a proper way.

Comment: @pravinraj66 - I see it, use `sep=','`. `sep='\s+'` is used if separator is space